# How do I add styles to windowManager popup in TinyMCE 4?

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

*note: please read comments.*

I'm rendering a jQuery template into a tinyMCE plugin I'm writing and I cant figure out how to style the **windowManager** window.

It looks like TinyMCE is simply overriding my styles, but I know there are ways to inject styles into the editor so I think this question is still valid.

**Here's my plugin:**

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function (editor, url) {
    var url = "ViewEditActivity.aspx/GetCourseOutlineFromActivity"
    editor.addButton('example', {
        text: 'Link Content',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function () {
            editor.windowManager.open({       
                title: 'Create Content Link',
                width: 800,
                height: 500,                   
                body: [
                    {
                        type: 'container',
                        onPostRender: function (e, f) {                  
                            OnDemandAdmin.CallJsonMethod(url, { "activityId": _activityId }, function (data) {
                                $("#coursetreefortinymcetmpl").tmpl(data.d).appendTo("#" + e.control._eventsRoot._id + "-body");
                                $("#" + e.control._eventsRoot._id + "-body a[href*='" + activityId + "']").parent().css("background-color", "silver");

                            });
                        }
                    }
                ],
                onsubmit: function (e) {
                    editor.insertContent('Title: ' + e.data.title);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Here's my initializer:**

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#htmlContentEditor",
    plugins: "code example",
    toolbar: "example",
    height: 400,
    //popup_css: "css/TinyMCE-CustomBody.css", <-- doesn't work
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on("change", tinymce_onchange_callback);
    }

});
```

To prove that there is markup being generated here's some markup directly form the windowManager **body source**:

```
<h2>
    <a href="ViewEditActivity.aspx?Id=cd20e736-eed7-4c49-b51b-1ef86c418687">Online Broker Prelicense Program ()</a>
</h2>
```

**Rendered Output:**

[image]

### How do I add styles to windowManager popup in TinyMCE 4?

---

**update:**

Based on @tvgemert's answer. I was able to add a tag to a siblings child, which doesn't help me in this scope unfortunately.

[image]

The blue arrow that points to the .mce-editor tag, which is the parent container of the windowManager editor that I need to style. Any tips on this would be most appreciated.

Comment: side note, I've already styled the window using !important tags. However it would still be nice to find a solution and remove those gross !importants.

Comment: So, styling rules using `!important` do give you your desired layout? In that case your current style definition is not specific enough. On the other hand, if you use the more specific styling rules without `!important` and it still doesn't honour your style something else is in the way. Gross as it may be, the `!important` still does the job.

Comment: @tvgemert true, also, although your answer didn't solve my problem specifically I think that its correct so I'll accept it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to first add a classname to the container, and then style elements through the stylesheet of your skin's

```
body: [
    {
        type: 'container',
        classes: 'myClassname',
        onPostRender: function (e, f) {                  
            OnDemandAdmin.CallJsonMethod(url, { "activityId": _activityId }, function (data) {
                $("#coursetreefortinymcetmpl").tmpl(data.d).appendTo("#" + e.control._eventsRoot._id + "-body");
                $("#" + e.control._eventsRoot._id + "-body a[href*='" + activityId + "']").parent().css("background-color", "silver");

            });
        }
    }
],
```

The rendered classname will in this case be `mce-myClassName`

Comment: so classes will add 'myClassname' to the body tag? I'll try it now. Thank you

Comment: ok, it adds it to the mce-container and prefixes it with mce-... +1, let me see if I can get this to work.

Comment: couldn't get it to help the situation, I've updated my main post, maybe Ive missed something

Comment: Hi Dan, are you sure the content you want to target is not within `mce-myClassName`? Usually, based on my own experience, this is where the plugin content is.

Comment: I've updated with a more useful image, hopefully this makes it clear what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to apply independent styles to elements.

Since the editor is located *inside* of an iframe, we need to use tinyMCE's framework to scope to the active editor window. Once we've scoped using `tinymce.activeEditor` we can easily do something like this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.$('p').css('color', 'red');
```

**[documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:property.tinymce.Editor.$)**